# Remove "x commits behind master" on branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I have the `master` branch, which is version 3 of my project.

Then, I created another branch named `v4`, which is version 4 of my project. However, version 4 is a completely new beginning of the project and is not an edited version of v3.

When I view the `v4` branch, it says "This branch is 50 commits ahead, 153 commits behind master."

As this is a new project, of some sort and not based around v3, how can I remove this? Basically, remove the tracking from 'master'?

Comment: Why are these two unrelated things in the same repo? Is there a point you didn't mention yet?

Comment: If you don't need the v3 at all, go ahead and merge the branches, that'll get rid of the message "x commits behind master” onthe  branch. But if you need to retain both of them, create a different project. And archive the v3 repo if you want.

Comment: @RomainValeri It's a new major version, meaning that the base is restructured and it has no correlation with v3 at all. It's just the same project, though, but as I said: "However, version 4 is a completely new beginning of the project and is not an edited version of v3."

Comment: @Smally I see no point in having both in the same repo. What's the added value?

Comment: @RomainValeri It's the same project, but it's a new beginning, basically

Answer (score 0):

You see this message because somehow, you indicated to git that your local `v4` branch should be compared to your `master` branch.

You can remove this link by simply typing :

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

from your `v4` branch.

(note : you can set it to track any other `branch_name` by running `git branch -u branch_name` ; you can also use a remote branch name here, `origin/v4` for example)